# How does one only configure minutes and seconds in any given cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to list a series of SAT test times for all the sections, and I can't figure out how to input my times as only minutes and seconds. I managed to figure out, in cell B5, that if I divide the entire (hh, mm, ss) time by 60, then my answer will be displayed. However, if I try to repeat the process for my next time, 15:40, I won't get the full time, and it just spits back 0:15, when I really wanted 0:15:40. The same thing happens when I try and input in 9:36 and 23:16. How do I configure my times so that they look like the first link?

Spreadsheet added for additional clarity: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L45OhbO-oh1GGF6T3VXIfKM2crloGNt0B-v0991SW1M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Hi Aero welcome to the forum!
Input something like 0:15:40 for a duration of 15 minutes and 40 seconds.  In this syntax the first number is hours, the second number in minutes and the third is seconds.